# October CMS, How to get values from checkboxes?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I've form with checkboxes:

```
{{ form_ajax('onAjaxList') }}
 {% for soc in socs %}
  <input type="checkbox" name="Filter[soc_id]" value="{{soc.id}}" id="
 {{soc.name}}">
{% endfor %}
{{ endform() }}
```

And i tried get values from controller:

```
$options = post('Filter',[]);
```

but in $options i get only last checkbox value and i need full array checkboxes. How to do it?

Comment: Checkbox name should be `Filter[]` instead of `Filter[soc_id]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input name should be like `name="Filter[soc_id][]"` instead of `name="Filter[soc_id]"` so change your input from

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Filter[soc_id]" value="{{soc.id}}" id="
 {{soc.name}}">
```

TO this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Filter[soc_id][]" value="{{soc.id}}" id="
 {{soc.name}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are `dealing` with `multiple checkbox` you always need to use `array`.

so adding `[]` square brackets **after name** will make it **array** and add `data index` will start from **0 index**.

> if you need more control you can also pass `name="Filter[soc_id][0]" , name="Filter[soc_id][1]", name="Filter[soc_id][2]" ...` **manually** if needed to use saved record's id, now array key will be your record's id.

In your case your code should look like this

```
{{ form_ajax('onAjaxList') }}
    {% for soc in socs %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="Filter[soc_id][]" value="{{soc.id}}" id="
        {{soc.name}}">
    {% endfor %}
{{ endform() }}
```

and from server side if you want to use filter

you can use this (October CMS, laravel)

```
$options = post('Filter',[]);    
$query->whereIn('soc_id', $options['soc_id']);
```

this will do the job, filtering based on `soc_id`.

if you have any doubts please comment.